# performance of linq extension method ElementAt

Tags: c#, .net, collections, polymorphism, linq-extensions

The MSDN library entry to `Enumerable.ElementAt(TSource)` Method says

> "If the type of source implements
>   IList, that implementation is used
>   to obtain the element at the specified
>   index. Otherwise, this method obtains
>   the specified element."

Let's say we have following example:

```
        ICollection<int> col = new List<int>() { /* fill with items */ };
        IList<int> list = new List<int>() { /* fill with items */ };

        col.ElementAt(10000000);
        list.ElementAt(10000000);
```

Is there any difference in execution? or does ElementAt recognize that `col` also implements IList<> although it's only declared as ICollection<>?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the variable itself is irrelevant to the `ElementAt` method - as far as *it's* concerned, it's only declared as `IEnumerable<T>`, because that's what the parameter type is. (Both calls will be bound to the same extension method.)

It's the execution-time type of the object which is tested in `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 0):

No, why there should be a difference. `ElementAt()` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`. There is no polymorphism in this case.